# Add new group to list and then it should be able to show bubble

Tags: jquery

```
 var bubble = $('.bubble');
    $('.bookmark-list').on('click', '.bookmark-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addBookmarkItem($(this));      
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="bookmark-list">
<div>
<a class="bookmark-link active" href="">
  test
  <span class="count">
    1
  </span>
</a>
</div>

//below new created bookmark group  
<div>
  <a class="bookmark-link" href="">
    test
    <span class="count">
      0
    </span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Save</a>
</div>
```

Tried to show bubble only if the bookmark-link is not ticked (as in active meaning ticked with count number more than 0). But the problem is that when on modal, type "example" in input and add it, then it will only show bubble bounce when click on that "example"
How to prevent bubble from showing if there is ticked bookmark-link?

**Updated**

```
 var count = $('.bookmark-link').find('.count').data('count');
if (count > 0) {
    bubble.hide;
} else {
    bubble.show();
    bubble.addClass('bounce');
}
```

Came up with this. it seems to be working but not sure if it is correct way

Comment: If it's working for you, then it's a correct way. :) Do you need to check if active?

Comment: @Mike - yes need to check if it is not yet added or active.. but i tried and it wouldn't work

Comment: When is addBookmark added? Always, or only once? You can use the `$(this).hasClass('active')` to exclude elements. Or use the jquery not:active selector. Like `$('bookmark-list').not('.active').on...`

Comment: @Mike - thanks. addBookmark is used only when click on bookmark list that we create via input. if hasClass('active'), it wouldn't know if we click on addbookmark or not?

Comment: No, it will still know with your current code. But in the `on`, you can put a check depending on what you want to do, i.e. `if ($this).hasClass('.active')) {bubble.hide()} else {do something else}`

Comment: @Mike -- thanks.. just realize that on modal, then i click on list the bubble wont be seen -- show behind overlay. I wonder if it is possible to check if it is bookmarked and then click save then bubble show?

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code to be sure, but yes, it should be possible. Does save refresh the screen at all?

Comment: And to be clear, did you want the bubble to not show if any of the bookmarks are active or just if the clicked bookmark is active?

Comment: @Mike - save wont refresh screen. but active bookmarks will be saved dynamically. it is correct that bubble should show if any of the clicked bookmarks are active

Comment: @mike -- do you want to see ajax for addbookmarkitem?

Comment: I think we can just do it on the save link click. Check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bookmark-list').on('click', '.bookmark-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addBookmarkItem($(this));
   if ($('.bookmark-link.active').children('.count').text()>0) {
        bubble.hide();
        bubble.removeClass('bounce');
        return;
   }else{
        bubble.show();
        bubble.addClass('bounce');
    }

});
```

I don't know if you want to add bookmark too, but this should do it. It checks the cooresponding count and only shows bubble if it is less than 1.

edit: put addBookmark where you want it, depending if you want to add a bookmark or not on click.

Edit: add this to show bubble on save with your parameters:

```
$('a.add').on('click', function(){
    if ($('.bookmark-link.active').children('.count').text()>0) {
        bubble.hide();
        bubble.removeClass('bounce');
   }else{
        bubble.show();
        bubble.addClass('bounce');
    }
}
```

When you click save, if any bookmark link has an active class and a count greater then 0, it will hide the bubble, else it will show the bubble.

edit for bootstrap modal:

```
$('#id of modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    if ($('.bookmark-link.active').children('.count').text()>0) {
        bubble.hide();
        bubble.removeClass('bounce');
   }else{
        bubble.show();
        bubble.addClass('bounce');
   }
}
```

We can tie the show bubble into the bootstrap modal close instead of the add button.

Comment: if add bookmark, wonder if your code shld be inside add bookmark function instead?

Comment: got it working - is there a way to delay the bubble show? delay()?

Comment: @joe - that would work, or a setTimeout, what is it waiting for? If it's the `addBookmarkItem` return, you could put the inner part of the code into the return of the ajax. If you post the ajax, we could find the best place.

Comment: yes when click add btn, it will take a few seconds for modal overlay to close. I do not want bubble to show at the same time closing modal upon click add btn. setTimeout should be set for bubble itself to show a few seconds after modal closes?

Comment: Well, you can put the code in the ajax return, but if you want a time out, just do: `$('a.add').on('click', function(){ if ($('.bookmark-link.active').children('.count').text()>0) {     bubble.hide(); bubble.removeClass('bounce');  }else{setTimeout(function() {bubble.show();       bubble.addClass('bounce');}, 2000);}}` That will delay it for 2 seconds. (2000 milliseconds)

Comment: i post ajax code but I am not sure if it is possible to delay inside ajax

Comment: @joe - What/where does the modal close then? if you want the bubble to show when the modal closes, what is it doing that it take a few seconds to close? Is there other ajax involved?

Comment: more like when a.add is clicked, modal will close. then bubble show up in bounce. I guess bootstrap modal takes a bit longer to close. No there is no ajax involved.

Comment: saw but it is not working because click is still required for add button. So after click button, it will close modal then show popup. I guess timeout is best option for now?  Edit: oops it is working because I forgot modal id. Interesting, so even if add button is not listened, it only listen to whether modal is closing or not. But how does it know if the links are clicked to be added? hmm. thanks a lot. Another edit: testing and whether I click to add bookmark or not, it still show bubble ha

Comment: @joe - yes, probably timeout then. If that's working, then use that one.

Comment: sadly it is same issue. They will check for count - supposedly if it is already clicked previously, it should be ignored. then only check whether it is newly clicked (starting from count: 0).. :(

Comment: got it working by moving code inside ajax and it works fine lol.

Comment: @joe - You can probably put in a test to check for count or add bookmark. With more code I can be more specific. Does this mean you don't want to call add bookmark if count > 1?